# If duplicate key, how do I determine which primary key (multi) triggered it

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I'm building a simple signup application on my website with user database.  I'm using PHP and MySQL.  I want take in "username" and "email".  Both are primary keys in my database.  I obviously don't want the same of either.  How can I provide feedback to the user if a) the username is already taken and b) the email is already used.  I know I can do a query on both but I thought this may be redundant (2 searches and an insert).  Is there a way to receive feedback from MySQL if I try to insert on a duplicate key.  As in, this it he field that failed on the insert.  If not, what is the best way/practice to do this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is execute the below:

```
$result = mysql_query( "insert into yourtable (`username`, `email`) values ('usernamesubmitted','emailsubmitted')");
if (!$result) {
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

The assumption here is that the insert query will fail if one of the fields to be inserted is a primary key and is being duplciated. In which case....output a message- the message will contain the max info you could get in this situation, you can then handle it as appropriate